# How to separate URL response data in ActionScripts3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a site that response to GET request in simple text format, I want to save data and title in separate variables.

Code:

```
 function URLRequest_method():void 
 { 
       var url:String = "http://sms-reg.ru/index.php"; 

       var getbalance:String      = "mode=api&apikey=*=getbalance"; 

       var postParams:URLVariables = new URLVariables(getbalance);

       var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
        request.data = postParams;

       var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
        urlLoader.load(request);

}

function onLoaderComplete( event:Event ):void
{
    var urlLoader2:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;

    txt_BALANCE1.text = urlLoader2.data; 

    trace( urlLoader2.data);

       //var json:Object = JSON.parse( urlLoader2.data );
       // trace( "json.response = ", json.response );

}

URLRequest_method();
```

Update:

```
    function onLoaderComplete( event:Event ):void
{
       var urlLoader2:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;
        trace( urlLoader2.data );

       //var json:Object = JSON.parse( urlLoader2.data );
       // trace( "json.response = ", json.response );
       var response:String = urlLoader2.data;

       var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("BALANCE:([0-9.-]+)");

       var data:Object = pattern.exec(response);

       if (data != null && data[1] != null) 
       {
         var value:Number = parseFloat(data[1]);
         trace(value);
       }

}
```

Outputs:
**BALANCE:123.00**

ID23:3(Telegram);ID28:4(Viber);ID29:6(Whatsapp);ID30:5(Instagram);

I need to separate title and data: "**BALANCE**" "**123**" OR "**ID23**"  "**3**" | each one in separate variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the value using a regular expression for example, something like this

```
var response:String = "BALANCE:123.00"

var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("BALANCE:([0-9.-]+)");

var data:Object = pattern.exec(response);

if (data != null && data[1] != null) {
    var value:Number = parseFloat(data[1]);
    trace(value);
}
```

The one i provided is fairly simple, to extract data from a known data format but, as long as there's a pattern in the string, you can extract the pieces of information you need.

Check out the guide on how to use [RegExp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdb.html) in actionscript

Comment: Thanks for response.

Comment: How code will be for "TZ_NUM_ANSWER:Telegram code 32263" ?